# Entity Framework FAILS to create a database from simple POCOs

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to created a very simple database using EF code first.

I defined this connection string

```
<add name="MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Created these models

```
namespace EF6Demo
{
    public class Contact
    {
        public Contact()
        {
            this.Jobs = new HashSet<Job>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Job
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Created this context class

```
namespace EF6Demo
{
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this one-line code, when I run the app, I get this error

[image]

**I thought EF was supposed to created this database based on my classes, context and connection string. What is wrong?**

Besides, in this MSDN article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/new-database

They use List for navigation properties, whereas in all tutorials they use ICollection. Is that a defect in documentation?

**UPDATE:**

If I just remove the connectionString from App.Config, then everything works just fine and the database **IS CREATED** once the code reaches

**var contacts = ctx.Contacts.ToList();** statement.

Here, the code passes just fine, no erros:

[image]

And the database is created in

c:\Users\myusername\EF6Demo.MyContext.mdf
c:\Users\myusername\EF6Demo.MyContext_log.ldf

So, everyone who said I have to insert something, are wrong.

The only tricky part is to create a database not in its default location in c:\myusername\ folder but in the location defined in Connection String.

**And that thing doesn't work, see exception above.**

Why **Initial Catalog=|DataDirectory|MyDatabase** in my connection string causes the problem?

Comment: Looks like you didn't try to save anything to the database.

Comment: Dont have to. Querying should work.

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework will create the tables after you create a migration and then update your database.  You have to do this before you execute your program.

If you are running entity framework core run the following commands in powershell or cmd prompt in your root project folder.

```
dotnet ef migrations add 'somename'
dotnet ef database update
```

After you generate a migration and run your update command, the table should exsist w/o data and you won't get the error you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to pull a list of Contacts without ever adding them to the database.

try :

```
Contact contact = new Contact(); 
contact.Name = "new name"; 
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
 ctx.Contact.Add(contact);
 ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

`

Comment: It is not required to add anything to the database in order to create it.